# launching applications from the Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-8, path, symbolic-link

Is there a Linux methodology to include `.exe` files symbolically to a location referenced by the `%PATH%`? The process seems trouble free on Linux, but when attempting to do similar actions via `mklink` on Windows as opposed to  `ln -s` on Linux I always seem to have issues regarding dependencies located in the original application root directory (like binaries, etc.) Thus I would like to know of a concrete example to add application launchers to a PATH location as to enable me to run them conveniently from the command prompt like launching Firefox via simple firefox command?

Comment: Is there a *Windows methodology* perhaps? Also one problem may be DLL searh order http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx since on Windows the shared libraries are often relative to the binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `your_link_name.cmd` file where you would want to put the link, with the following contents:

```
start /D c:/path/to/working/directory c:/path/to/working/directory/example.exe %*
```

`%*` should pass any arguments given.

If you need to wait until the process finishes you are better off with `psexec` from sysinternals, now microsoft, see [homepage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553). I remember start+cmd being buggy in this respect.

```
psexec -w c:/working_dir c:/working_dir/example.exe %*
```

In arguments, file paths must be absolute paths on the target system.

Comment: Note: while `/` works in windows as a path separator, some executables just don't realize this and won't accept it. Also it doesn't always work with `UNC` paths with some resources. But psexec and start themselves should have no problems with it.

Comment: I would do a `cd` before the command (if working directory is applicable) and a `pause` after (also if needed).

Comment: @Javier the `/D` for the `start` command, and the `-w` for the `psexec` command take care for changing directory. So `cd` is unnecessary. As for `pause`, it is useful for manual execution from windows double-clicking to see the output. However from script or from cmd it could stop the script. Even manually I'd prefer running from total commander's prompt and adding `|more` or `2>&1 |more` to its end, the latter showing also the standard error stream. (Actually I use `|less` from unxutils). If you go with cd you could end the .cmd with a new line `@exit /b %errorlevel%` to return the exit code.

Comment: @Javier also, I think `start` creates a new second window for the command and will *not* wait in the first window for the second one to finish. So in this case doing `pause` is tricky.

Comment: I am used to `.bat` and not using `start`. Quite more old-school and rudimentary. lol